# Syncing Firefox passwords between 2 computers - FF >= 57

Tags: firefox, passwords, sync, merge

I am using Firefox Quantum (v60).
I have some passwords stored in my current profile (#1).
I am also using FF in another computer (#2), with other passwords.
I mean to merge the two password lists into my current pc/profile (#1).

From what I found on the web, one could use [FF sync](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/features/sync/).

**Is there any way of doing the merge locally? (i.e., without sending my info to a third party)**

The closest I could get is using [PasswordFox](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/passwordfox.html) (thanks Nir Sofer once again!) to reveal the passwords from one installation, and copy-paste one at a time. This avoids typing them, but it is still quite cumbersome.

PS: I do not want to *export-import* (#2 -> #1), I already know how to do that. I mean to *merge* passwords.

Related info:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/959278

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1143122

Comment: Your 1st Mozilla Support link has numerous solutions, but the thread is dated.  Have you tried those to see if any still work?

Comment: @fixer1234 - Password Exporter supports only FF <= 56; I am not even sure it supports merging, but it is not relevant anyway. The other option posted useful for merging is FF sync, which I mean to avoid.